# rails 3 group by date a datetime column

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Foo.group(:start_at).count(:id)
```

How I can group this by date ? the "start_at" column is an datetime column

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This should work (rails 3):

```
Foo.order(:start_at).group("DATE(start_at)").count
```

edit: if you're using PostgreSQL, the query should be

```
Foo.order("DATE(start_at)").group("DATE(start_at)").count
```

or you'll get an error

```
("PGError: ERROR:  column "foos.start_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function")
```

Based on

[Graphing new users by date in a Rails app using Seer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440957/graphing-new-users-by-date-in-a-rails-app-using-seer)

and

http://www.pastbedti.me/2009/11/grouping-a-timestamp-field-by-date-in-ruby-on-rails-postgresql/

Answer (score 16):

I created a gem for this. https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

```
Foo.group_by_day(:created_at).count
```

You can even specify a time zone.

```
Foo.group_by_day(:created_at, time_zone: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)").count
```

Comment: This doesn't work without access to mysql time zones on the server. A challenge with AWS

Comment: Pretty large dependency if you're using mysql, was a deal breaker for me.

Comment: Are you kidding me? large dependency? its 54kb unzipped

Comment: Is there a way to get the items instead of the count with this gem?

Comment: @CarlosMartinez you can use `Foo.all.to_a.group_by_day(&:created_at)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to solve this if you manage different time zones. The idea is to add or substract the hours of your timezone:

```
hours_diff = Time.zone.now.time_zone.utc_offset/(60*60) rescue 0
hours_diff = hours_diff.to_i
date_group = "DATE(form_answers.created_at)"
if hours_diff > 0
  date_group = "DATE(DATE_ADD(form_answers.created_at, INTERVAL #{hours_diff} HOUR ))"
elsif hours_diff < 0
  date_group = "DATE(DATE_SUB(form_answers.created_at, INTERVAL #{hours_diff.abs} HOUR ))"
end
Foo.group(date_group).count
```