# Formatting output of group by date in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043109/rails-3-group-by-date-a-datetime-column) post for instructions on grouping a set of results by the date and adding a count.

The output in my view looks like this:

```
 {Sun, 30 Oct 2011=>17, Wed, 02 Nov 2011=>19, Fri, 11 Nov 2011=>70, Sat, 12 Nov 2011=>44, Sun, 13 Nov 2011=>38, Sun, 20 Nov 2011=>4, Mon, 21 Nov 2011=>5, Sun, 27 Nov 2011=>80, Sun, 04 Dec 2011=>16, Sat, 31 Dec 2011=>48, Mon, 02 Jan 2012=>68, Tue, 03 Jan 2012=>1, Wed, 04 Jan 2012=>3, Sun, 08 Jan 2012=>9, Mon, 09 Jan 2012=>7, Wed, 11 Jan 2012=>1, Thu, 12 Jan 2012=>1}
```

I have this is my controller:

```
@radpostauth = Radpostauth.order(:authdate).group("DATE(authdate)").count
```

I'm not sure how to format this output in a table? Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query is going to return a hash, so all you need to do is iterate over the hash and display it in a table.

Here's a quick example of iterating over it:

```
$ hashish = Hash.new
$ hashish = {'Sun, 30 Oct 2011'=>17, 'Wed, 02 Nov 2011'=>19, 'Fri, 11 Nov 2011'=>70, 'Sat, 12 Nov 2011'=>44, 'Sun, 13 Nov 2011'=>38, 'Sun, 20 Nov 2011'=>4, 'Mon, 21 Nov 2011'=>5, 'Sun, 27 Nov 2011'=>80, 'Sun, 04 Dec 2011'=>16, 'Sat, 31 Dec 2011'=>48, 'Mon, 02 Jan 2012'=>68, 'Tue, 03 Jan 2012'=>1, 'Wed, 04 Jan 2012'=>3, 'Sun, 08 Jan 2012'=>9, 'Mon, 09 Jan 2012'=>7, 'Wed, 11 Jan 2012'=>1, 'Thu, 12 Jan 2012'=>1}
$ hashish.each {|k,v| puts "Key is #{k} and value is #{v}"}

> Key is Sun, 30 Oct 2011 and value is 17
> Key is Wed, 02 Nov 2011 and value is 19
> Key is Fri, 11 Nov 2011 and value is 70
> Key is Sat, 12 Nov 2011 and value is 44
> Key is Sun, 13 Nov 2011 and value is 38
> Key is Sun, 20 Nov 2011 and value is 4
> Key is Mon, 21 Nov 2011 and value is 5
> Key is Sun, 27 Nov 2011 and value is 80
> Key is Sun, 04 Dec 2011 and value is 16
> Key is Sat, 31 Dec 2011 and value is 48
> Key is Mon, 02 Jan 2012 and value is 68
> Key is Tue, 03 Jan 2012 and value is 1
> Key is Wed, 04 Jan 2012 and value is 3
> Key is Sun, 08 Jan 2012 and value is 9
> Key is Mon, 09 Jan 2012 and value is 7
> Key is Wed, 11 Jan 2012 and value is 1
> Key is Thu, 12 Jan 2012 and value is 1
```

Here's a quick example of displaying in a table (I'm using HAML code since you didn't specify ERB or HAML):

```
%table
  %tr
    - hashish.each do |k,v|
      %td #{k}
  %tr
    - hashish.each do |k,v|
      %td #{v}
```

Or

```
%table
  - hashish.each do |k,v|
    %tr
      %td #{k}
      %td #{v}
```