# Rails Show Subtotal by Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using mySQL for my Rails 4 app and I have a `Sale` model that has the fields `sale_date`, `amount`, and `user_id`.

What I'm trying to do is show the total amount per sale date.

```
<% @sales.each do |sale| %>      
   <%= sale.sale_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
   <%= number_to_currency(sale.amount) %>
<% end %>
```

Currently, my controller only has this (which obviously doesn't subtotal):

```
@sales = @user.sales
```

How can I show sales subtotaled by date? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% @sales.group_by(&:sale_date).each do |sale| %>      
   <%= sale[0].strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
   <%= number_to_currency(sale[1].sum(&:amount)) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with scopes in rails I recommend you to read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

A possible solution to your problem is to add the following scope to your `Sales` model.

```
scope :amount_per_sale, -> { group(:sale_date).sum(:amount) }
```

This scope will produse `hash` which contains the dates of a sale as keys and the amount as values.
If you want to use this scope in combination with user instance it's very easy too.

```
@user.sales.amount_per_sale
```

Comment: Thanks!  I received this error `undefined method `sale_date' for [Mon, 12 Dec 2016, #<BigDecimal:bbcbc90,'0.65E0',9(18)>]:Array` on `<td><%= number_to_currency(sale.amount) %></td>`

Comment: This is because the result of this scope is not `ActiveRecord::Relation`. It is a `Hash`

Comment: You can iterate over it like this

Comment: `each do |key, value|
   Sale.find(key).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
   number_to_currency(value)
end`

Comment: Sorry for the 3 long comments answer, I'm new in this.

Comment: Thanks Stanislav Gospodinov!  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but when I  put this in the view `<% @sales.each do |key, value| Sale.find(key).strftime("%m/%d/%Y") number_to_currency(value) %>` to replace `<% @sales.each do |sale| %>`, I get this error `C:/Sites/sales/app/views/sales/index.html.erb:22: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end ...("%m/%d/%Y") number_to_currency(value) ... ^`. In my controller `@sales= @user.sales.subtotal`.  In the model, `  scope :subtotal, -> { group(:sale_date).sum(:amount) }`

Comment: You should write something like: `<% sales.each does |key, value| %>
  <%= Sale.find(key).strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
  <%= number_to_currency(value) %>
<%= end %>` This is syntaxis error.

Comment: Sorry my fault the end of the code segment must be `<% end %>` without = before the `end` key word

Comment: Hmmmm.  I have this error now `undefined method `strftime' for #<Sale:0x991fe30>` for this line `<%= Sale.find(key).strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>`.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought, if there are not too many @sales, we can use ruby group_by method to group by sale_date. Ideally, it would be:

```
<% sales_group = @sales.to_a.group_by{ |sale| sale.sale_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") } %>
<% @sales_group.each do |sale_group| %>      
   <%= sale_group.first.sale_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
   <%= number_to_currency(sale_group.sum(&:amount)) %>
<% end %>
```

You can move the logic of sales_group to controller & if there is a lot of @sales records, you may use database query instead of ruby.

This is a good reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061462/1789479

Comment: Thanks!  I receive the error "undefined method `sale_date' for "12/12/2016":String" for this line `   <%= sale_group.first.sale_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>`